# How to respond to doubt of logic?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, non-muslim, doubts, imaan, interfaith

WARNING: Read this at your own risk of losing your beliefs.

I don't believe in Islam (but hopefully I would). I thought I was the only one ever who doubts the truthfulness of rationality, perception and reports, but I recently [asked on Philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92551/can-we-doubt-all-knowledge), and I found people, who are reputable in philosophy, doubt all kinds of knowledge...

The reasons for doubting that logic is true:

- The existence of free will; because it indicates indeterminism, which is illogical
- Why not? What makes it impossible that there is another way of thinking that leads to truth?

How can Islamic scientests respond to such doubts? If someone doubts logic, Does that mean he can never become a true believer in Islam?

Answer (score 2):

In logic, there is an important concept known as an "axiom", which is defined as "a statement accepted as true as the basis for argument or inference". These are elements that are not defined logically, rather they are simply accepted as true in and of themselves, and they are the foundation upon which any logical conclusion is built upon.

If an axiom cannot be proven in and of itself, its acceptance is entirely a matter of belief; this has nothing to do with religion, simply a concession that we can't (or don't yet) *know* everything, but we need to start *somewhere*.

This is entirely compatible with Islam: One major concept in Islam, one of the pillars of Imaan, is acceptance of *al-Ghaib* — the Unseen — those things which are fundamentally unobservable and that we only know via revelation. These are things faithful Muslims simply accept as true, regardless of proof.

If logic leads you to a conclusion that is illogical or obviously untrue, that's not a failure of logic, that's a failure of one or more of the axioms you're working with, a failure of the foundation you built on. You just need to revisit your initial assumptions.

Muslims don't worship logic, we worship Allah who guides whosoever He wills to the truth. Ultimately, Allah either exists, or He does not, and whether His existence or His revelations are logically provable is irrelevant.

You either believe, or you do not.

Comment: Then how come Allah is merciful and just even though he would judge me according to my choice to believe or not believe in something that can't be proven?

Comment: @AZeed Comments are not for tangential discussion; I answered the question you originally asked. If you have another question, ask it separately.